# Liferay avoid loading files from /html/ folder

Tags: html, css, performance, liferay

We are liferay 6.1.2. Have got 3 portlets on 3 different pages. We have our own set of JS files and CSS files which are self sufficient for the page to work. I see that there are lots of files loaded from /html/js and /html/css. How can we avoid loading these files. I am pretty sure that none of the rules from these CSS files are used in our page.

Comment: use inline css and javascript? what do you expect as an answer? also source code is nice to have. This question will never get an answer with this lack of explanation. Please improve your question, so I can better understand.

Comment: `/html/js` or `/html/css` are core portal files, required to add basic scripting features and styles. Removing these would cause issues for sure.

Comment: @ParkashKumar I want to check if this is going cause any problem. Any ways to not to load them?

Comment: So these css and scripts are actually used in your pages and and it is not at all advisable to prevent it from loading.Also they are minified by default to reduce number of http requests.

Comment: Are you using custom theme for your portal?

Comment: @ParkashKumar Yes we are using our own full fledged theme.

Answer (score 1):

Liferay's pages bring a lot of functionality with them - e.g. the theme might provide libraries, other components on the page (like the dockbar) might use that functionality.

In the case of Liferay's core themes, they provide the AlloyUI library and your portlets *can* just assume that this library is available. If you don't need it, make sure there's no other portlet on the page that needs it as well (e.g. Dockbar, Chat, Notification portlet)

On the CSS side, Liferay loads quite a bit of CSS from the theme - bootstrap CSS among it all. Eliminate it and then try to get your layout back... It's typically all minified and combined into a single file anyway.

You can configure the files that get loaded for anonymous users and for logged in users in [portal-ext.properties](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html). Search for "barebone" and "everything" in the linked document. Also make sure that you haven't disabled the CSS- and JS-minifier. Disabling them is recommended during development. In production they should be enabled.

Comment: Well defined as always.